# Android - Return value get in a custom listener

Tags: android, static, listener

Please excuse my french english !

So, I have got a problem in my Android code...
I call a method which much return a arrayList of a custom object... but this arrayList is loaded asynchronously and returned in a listener.

Do you know how I could return datas when the method of my listener is called ?

Here my code :

```
    public static ArrayList<Advert> getAdverts(Context context) {
    // Initialize
    RestHelper restHelper = new RestHelper();

    // Set the listener
    restHelper.setOnRestListener(new OnRestListener<Advert>() {
        @Override
        public void onDataAvailable(ArrayList<Advert> result) {
            // -- Datas are loaded : now we must return them ! --
        }
    });

    // Launch the async query
    restHelper.getRemoteAdverts();
    }
```

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the problem. You have an async method that you can call, but it can't return your result since its an async method, so you have 2 solutions :
 - Wait in the method that all data are available, but you loose the async benefits.
 - Implements an Oberserver/Observable pattern.

For the first option, look into the RestHelper, maybe you have already the solution.
Example for the second option :

```
public static void requestAdverts(Context context) {
RestHelper restHelper = new RestHelper();
final AdvertListener thisInstance = this;
restHelper.setOnRestListener(new OnRestListener<Advert>() {
    @Override
    public void onDataAvailable(ArrayList<Advert> result) {
        thisInstance.notifyDataLoaded(result);
    }
});
// Launch the async query
restHelper.getRemoteAdverts();
```

Create an Interface :

```
interface AdvertListener { 
    notifyDataLoaded(ArrayList<Advert> result);
}
```

And finally let the main class (the one that call the requestAdverts method) implements your new interface.

Answer (score 0):

Well, please revisit your function design, you are tiring to make asynchronously load inside a synchronous function (getAdverts). If your function is synchronous, then just synchronously load the list and return.

If for any reason, if you want to go ahead with current approach, please block the caller after setOnRestListener and when you get a callback(onDataAvailable) unlock it and return your list.

You can use ConditionVariable, for this.

Block the caller:
ConditionVariable.block ();
ConditionVariable.close ();

UnBlock/open the caller:
ConditionVariable.open ();
Hope, this helps.